# Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 30000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Whatever I did, still cant make the tests run correctly. Although through the all other posts i tried all possible solutions, still doesn't work.
With setting the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;`I thought it would work but no success.
Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
  let therapistStatus = TherapistStatus;

  let id = '';
  let firstName = '';
  let lastName = '';
  let email = '';
  let status = 2;
  let statusChanges = '';
  let therapist = new Therapist({id, firstName, lastName, email, status, statusChanges});


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        OAuthModule.forRoot(),
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()

      ],
      providers: [UserService]
    })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the dashboard component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make the module instantiation async. Try removing and Modify your code as following (Please check for parenthesis miss). Hope this helps.

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
  let therapistStatus = TherapistStatus;

  let id = '';
  let firstName = '';
  let lastName = '';
  let email = '';
  let status = 2;
  let statusChanges = '';
  let therapist = new Therapist({id, firstName, lastName, email, status, statusChanges});


  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        OAuthModule.forRoot(),
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()

      ],
      providers: [UserService]
    }).compileComponents();
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the dashboard component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

  });
```